# How to add content using stringbuilder into UpdatePanel in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, updatepanel, stringbuilder

I am creating a dynamic html content using StringBuilder and i want to know how to append inside of UpdatePanel in asp.net?

Code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<div>Hello World</div>");

UpdatePanel panel = new UpdatePanel();
panel.Controls.Add(sb); // Can't add stringbuilder in update panel.
```

How we can add dynamic html codes into the updatepanel?

Comment: A string is not a control. You'd need to create a control to add to a controls collection. But anyways, don't just declare your UpdatePanel in the code behind. It should be declared on the markup, and you should probably place a place holder or other control inside of it, in the markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add stringbuilder in to updatepanel because updatepanel waits for a control and it's better if you can use contenttemplatecontainer to add control.

**Example**:

```
updatepanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(control); // Add control into
```

Before do that, you need to create a control which has "innerHTML" propery or somekind. Than you can add stringbuilder to control and finally, add your control to the updatepanel.

I hope this will help you.